# Odd line spacing in title in modernCV

Tags: moderncv, line-spacing

I am looking for help. I have the impression that the line spacing is wrong in `\title` in `moderncv` if title contains so many information that they are distributed over two lines. Do you have an idea how to fix this, please? Or do you have a better idea for the design, please?
Many thanks!

I think the definition of title is just:

```
\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\@title{#1}}
```

My mini working example is as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{moderncvcompatibility}
\usepackage{moderncvstyleclassic}

\usepackage[left=1.7cm, right=1.7cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}


\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}

\title{Chemist\protect\\[0.2\baselineskip]
Inorganic Chemistry, Organic Chemistry, Software development, Instrumentation, R\&D}

\address{Musterhausen, Musterland}{}{}
\email{max.muster@gmail.com}
\phone{+1 123456789}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Work Experience}
\end{document}
```

Output as PDF:
[image]

Comment: The real typesetting is made by another macro --- the `\title` you cited simply store the argument in `\@title`. There should be a `\maketitle` or something in the macro that *uses* `\@title`... (no idea about this package, sorry...)

Comment: I tried to investigate further. In moderncv.cls I find 
\newcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  \makecvhead%
  \makecvfoot}
\newcommand*{\makecvhead}{}
\newcommand*{\makecvfoot}{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would simply use an dirty workaround: add an second `\protect\\[0.2\baselineskip]` before `Software` in your title.

Complete workaround:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} %
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[left=1.7cm, right=1.7cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\name{Max}{Mustermann}

\title{Chemist\protect\\[0.2\baselineskip]%
Inorganic Chemistry, Organic Chemistry, \protect\\[0.2\baselineskip]% <================
Software development, Instrumentation, R\&D}

\address{Musterhausen, Musterland}{}{}
\email{max.muster@gmail.com}
\phone{+1 123456789}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Work Experience}
\end{document}
```

resulting in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is '[0.2\baselineskip]' the normal spacing between two lines in moderncv or did you choose this distance randomly, please?

Comment: @Gudrun  I choosed the same value you used before :-)  The normal spacing between two lines is `\baselineskip` ...

Comment: Thank you for your help.